# Why Npgsql sometimes not responding?

Tags: npgsql

I using Npgsql 3.2.2
I connect to database of Web server:

```
   <add key="CONNECTION_STRING_WEBSERVER" value="Server=abctest.com;Port=5432;UserId=postgres;Password=postgres;Database=testdatabase;CommandTimeout=300;" />
```

My query to get data:

```
Dim sql="Select * from table1;"
```

my function:

```
private DataTable getData(string tableName)
    {
        DataSet ds = null;
        DataTable tbl = null;

        try
        {

            if (m_ConnectionExecute == null)
            {
                 m_ConnectionExecute = new NpgsqlConnection(m_connString_web);                 

            }
            if (m_ConnectionExecute.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                m_ConnectionExecute.Open();               
            }

            NpgsqlDataAdapter adapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter();            
            NpgsqlCommand command = null;
            try
            {
                command = CreateCommand(m_Parameters);
                command.CommandText = m_commText;
                command.Connection = m_ConnectionExecute;
                adapter.SelectCommand = command;

                ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds, "Table1");
                tbl = ds.Tables[0];
                tbl.TableName = tableName;
                ds.Tables.Clear();

            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                ds = null;
            }
            finally
            {
                if ( m_ConnectionExecute != null && m_ConnectionExecute.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    m_ConnectionExecute.Close();                   
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            ds = null;
            tbl = null;
        }      

        return tbl;
    }
```

I using Timer : 5s will call function `getData`.

But sometimes, function getData not respond and my program can't continue next process.

The problem only occur when Timer run some days and database put on a web server.
Notes: I have 5 Timer run auto access database.

what is the cause? or limit of postgresql?
Why Npgsql sometimes not responding?

Comment: Wow. Two exception-eating catch clauses. How about removing them to get the actual cause?

Comment: I try run program from Visual Studio 2012, If click pause, it will stop at row: NpgsqlDataAdapter adapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter();

Comment: @UweKeim is right, modify your code to make exceptions bubble up rather than swallowing them, this way you'll know what's actually happening. It's very unlikely that the instantiation of NpgsqlDataAdapter is blocking in any way - nothing's happening there.

Comment: If it occur exception, Timer will not stop. the problem is Ngpsql not reponding. so it can't finish function getData.